# Qt QRadioButton setChecked

Tags: c++, qt

In my form constructor I check the status of various members and then call setChecked with true or false according to the state for radio buttons.

I would have expected this to then invoke the callback / slot associated with the radio button, it does not or isn't working.  For example I have two radio buttons on my form, rdoOn and rdoOff, in my constructor I check the states and then call:

```
    ui->rdoOn->setChecked(true);
```

or

```
    ui->rdoOn->setChecked(false);
```

I have slots in the class to deal with these and these are called when I click on the radio button but not when I call setChecked.

```
    void clsName::on_rdoOn_clicked() {
    ...
    }
```

Is there anyway short of calling the slot directly to link the calling of the slot with calling setChecked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`toggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal:

***.h**

```
class clsName: ....
{
// ...
private Q_SLOTS:
    void onToggled(bool checked);
// ...
};
```

***.cpp**

```
// constructor
connect(ui->rdoOn, &QAbstractButton::toggled, this, &clsName::onToggled);

void clsName::onToggled(bool checked){
    qDebug() << checked;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, any example on how?  Do I just connect to it?

Comment: @SPlatten in your case change `on_rdoOn_clicked()` to `on_rdoOn_toggled(bool checked)` in the .h and .cpp of your form, delete the build folder and compile again

Comment: @SPlatten see the update. You should also see that signal available in the same form with which you created the on_rdoOn_clicked slot using Qt Designer